# Binary nodes overlapping at level 5

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

How can I prevent nodes from overlapping in a binary tree?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {minimum width = 1em, draw, circle},
  level/.style = {sibling distance = 80mm/#1}
  ]
  \node {7}
  child {node {6} 
        child {node {5}
                   child {node {4}
                       child {node {3}
                               child {node {2}}
                                child {node {1}}
                               }
                       child {node {2}}
                      }
               child {node {3}
                       child {node {2}}
                       child {node {1}}
                      }
        }
        child {node {4}
               child {node {3}
                       child {node {2}}
                       child {node {1}}
                       }
               child {node {2}}
              }
        }
  child {node {5}
         child {node {4}
                child {node {3}
                        child {node {2}}
                        child {node {1}}
                        }
                child {node {2}}
               }
         child {node {3}
                child {node {2}}
                child {node {1}}
                }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the sibbling distance manually for each level:

[image: binary tree]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {minimum width = 1em, draw, circle},
  level/.style = {sibling distance = 80mm/#1},
  level 3/.style = {sibling distance = 20mm},
  level 4/.style = {sibling distance = 10mm}
  ]
  \node {7}
  child {node {6} 
        child {node {5}
                   child {node {4}
                       child {node {3}
                               child {node {2}}
                                child {node {1}}
                               }
                       child {node {2}}
                      }
               child {node {3}
                       child {node {2}}
                       child {node {1}}
                      }
        }
        child {node {4}
               child {node {3}
                       child {node {2}}
                       child {node {1}}
                       }
               child {node {2}}
              }
        }
  child {node {5}
         child {node {4}
                child {node {3}
                        child {node {2}}
                        child {node {1}}
                        }
                child {node {2}}
               }
         child {node {3}
                child {node {2}}
                child {node {1}}
                }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forest` computes all distances between nodes for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [7, for tree={circle, draw, minimum size=2em}
    [6  [5  [4  [3  [2] [1]]
                        [2]]
            [3  [2] [1]]]
        [4  [3  [2] [1]]
            [2]]]
    [5  [4  [3  [2]
                [1]]
            [2]]
        [3  [2]
            [1]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]